# Number of records in WARC file

Tags: warc

I currently parsing WARC files from CommonCrawl corpus and I would like to know upfront, without iterating through all WARC records, how many records are there.

Does WARC 1.1 standard defines such information?

Comment: What is the reason to close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WARC standard does not define a standard way to indicate the number of WARC records in the WARC file itself. The number of response records in Common Crawl WARC files is usually between 30,000 and 50,000 - note that there are also request and metadata records. The WARC standard recommends [1 GB as target size of WARC files](http://iipc.github.io/warc-specifications/specifications/warc-format/warc-1.1/#annex-c-informative-warc-file-size-and-name-recommendations) which puts a natural limit to the number of records.